# Is there a more pythonic way of writing a loop that modifies a list?

Tags: python

I am looking to see if there is a more pythonic way of writing this for-loop:

```
for x in y:
    z[x] = func(x)
```

Here, `z` is a list, although I guess it could be any indexable container.

Comment: no, that's a perfectly pythonic way of modifying a list

Comment: What is `y`? Is every element in `z` an identical function of the whole of `y`? Or are you simply looking for something like `z = [func(item) for item in y]`?

Comment: first: I think you mean `func(x)` instead of `func(y)'. second: is y a numeric range.

Comment: I think that too.

Comment: Otherwise a more efficient way is: `val = func(y); for x in y: z[x] = val`.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes that was a mistake, it's meant to be `func(x)`

Comment: @Tumbleweed53, are the lengths of z and y the same?

Comment: @Tumbleweed53, list(map(func, y)) gives you a list whose i-th element is func(y[i]). Not sure how to copy its elements to the appropriate positions of z.

Comment: No, the lengths are not the same.

Comment: I don't see what is not pythonic in this code. 

```for x in y:
        z[x] = func(x)``` 

seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
z = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
y = [3, 4, 6]
def func(x): return str(x)

z = list(map(lambda v: func(z.index(v)) if z.index(v) in y else v, z))
print(z)
```

Below is the result, which is the same as that of your code:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '3', '4', 'f', '6'].
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not quite understand func(y). But if your trying to get a list by passing each element through the func(). Use this

```
[func(x) for x in y]
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Also, the indices of z need not start from 0. For instance, y can be range(10, 20).

Comment: That's actually not what I'm looking for, because I need to only set the elements of `z` that are contained in `y`

Comment: That answer seems correct with the addition of `z[x] = `. So, it would be like: `z[x] = [func(x) for x in y]`

Comment: I don't think that code will work, will it?  Don't you mean `z = [func(x) for x in y]`?  That still won't work because `z` may contain other elements.